# libopencv_calib3d: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, …)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'

Tags: opencv, c++, qt

I referred to [this](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/) to install OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 2 (which is running on the latest Raspbian with kernel release 4.1.7-v7). I was not able to install libgtk2.0-dev due to dependency errors but I was able to install OpenCV without any errors.

I am trying to cross-compile some simple OpenCV code in Qt for my Raspberry Pi 2. But I am getting the following error at linker stage:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so: undefined reference to
std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20
```

My code is:

```
myFunc {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open the video cam";
        return;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    qDebug() << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight;
    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1) {
        Mat frame;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);

         if (!bSuccess) {
             qDebug() << "Cannot read a frame from video stream";
             break;
         }

         imshow("MyVideo", frame);

         if (/*condition*/) {
            break; 
         }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the order in which the libraries are linked. But the error still remains. My `.pro` file looks this:

```
QT       += core gui quick xml widgets
TARGET = myApp
TEMPLATE = app

    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include/libxml2 \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0 \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 \
                      -I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/local/include \

    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-psabi

    QMAKE_LIBDIR_FLAGS += -L/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/lib \
                          -L/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/lib \
                          -L/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/local/lib \

    QMAKE_LFLAGS   += -lgmodule-2.0 \
                      -lz \
                      -lxml2 \
                      -lgthread-2.0 \
                      -lrt \
                      -lglib-2.0 \
                      -lpthread \
                      -lgstreamer-1.0 \
                      -lgobject-2.0 \
                      -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video \

SOURCES += /* all .cpp files */

HEADERS += /* all .h files */
```

How can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

I managed to install libgtk2.0-dev and compile OpenCV again. But the error remains.

Comment: Have you tried to install the dependencies of [libgtk2.0-dev](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgtk2.0-dev) before?

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same experience. I'm assuming you are using https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools as your toolchain, but even if you are not the problem is that whatever toolchain you are using it probably predates gcc/g++ 4.9.

The problem is that Jessie (i.e. Raspbian 4.1.X) uses gcc/g++ 4.9 as its toolchain and OpenCV is making use of an STL feature that is new to that version of the compiler. Therefore if your application is built with a toolchain that predates gcc/g++ 4.9, it will not link.

The solution is to either get a toolchain that is at least  4.9 or greater, or stick with the Wheezy release of Raspbian, which uses gcc 4.6.

I detailed my experience with cross compiling an OpenCV app in a post here: https://solderspot.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi-part-ii.

Hope it is of some help.