# Cross-Compile for Raspberry pi opencv linking problems

Tags: linux, opencv, linker, cross-compiling, toolchain

(Sorry for bad English, I'm German)
Hello programmers,
I'm desperately trying to cross compile a program (using OpenCV) on my linux(fedora) x86_x64 laptop for a linux(raspian) Raspberry pi 3.

I'm following this tutorial (https://solderspot.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi-part-ii/) and a simple std::cout << "test\n"; program compiles and works fine with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (CVS)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
SET(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -Werror)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_definitions(-DHOST_ROBO_DIR=/home/username/Dropbox/Roboter)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${PIROOT}/opt/vc/include ${PIROOT}/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads ${PIROOT}/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux )
link_directories( ${PIROOT}/opt/vc/lib )
add_executable (CVS ../source/main.cpp)
```

The Problem comes with OpenCV...
If I use the CMakeLists.txt from above it generates (for obvious reasons) many "undefined reference" errors eg.: "undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'"

If I add "target_link_libraries( CVS ${OpenCV_LIBS} )" or "target_link_libraries(CVS -lopencv_core)" to the CMakeLists.txt make produces the following error:
/home/username/pidev/piroot/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'

If I replace "SET(TOOLROOT ${PITOOLS}/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64)" in ~/pidev/pi-toolchain.cmake with "SET(TOOLROOT ${PITOOLS}/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf)"  I got the following error:

```
[username@MSI-Linux msi]$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/pidev/pi-toolchain.cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler
  "/home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_b1abe/fast"

  /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/build

  gmake[1]: Verzeichnis
  „/home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“
  wird betreten

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o


  /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
  --sysroot=/home/username/pidev/piroot
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/opt/vc/lib
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/usr/local/lib -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  Linking C executable cmTC_b1abe

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/link.txt
  --verbose=1


  /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
  --sysroot=/home/username/pidev/piroot
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/opt/vc/lib
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/username/pidev/piroot/usr/local/lib
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_b1abe -rdynamic


  /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
  cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory


  /home/username/pidev/pitools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
  cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory

  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1abe.dir/build.make:97: die Regel für Ziel
  „cmTC_b1abe“ scheiterte

  gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_b1abe] Fehler 1

  gmake[1]: Verzeichnis
  „/home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“
  wird verlassen

  Makefile:126: die Regel für Ziel „cmTC_b1abe/fast“ scheiterte

  gmake: *** [cmTC_b1abe/fast] Fehler 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/username/Dropbox/Roboter/raspySync/CVS/cvs5-6/msi/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[username@MSI-Linux msi]$
```

I would be thankful if anyone could answer one of these questions:
- How can I cross-compile a program that uses OpenCV commands
- Why is there an "undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'" and a "The C compiler ... is not able to compile a simple test program."
- Would it be bad or REALLY bad style if I add a something like this in the program:

```
namespace std
{
void __throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...) 
{
  std::cout << "throw out of range error\n";
}
}
```

Heres my ~/pidev/pi-toolchain.cmake:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(DEVROOT $ENV{HOME}/pidev)
SET(PIROOT ${DEVROOT}/piroot)
SET(PITOOLS ${DEVROOT}/pitools)

SET(TOOLROOT ${PITOOLS}/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${TOOLROOT}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLROOT}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${PIROOT})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${PIROOT})


# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

SET(FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath-link,${PIROOT}/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,${PIROOT}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,${PIROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,${PIROOT}/usr/local/lib")

UNSET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS CACHE)
UNSET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CACHE)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${FLAGS} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${FLAGS} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory"-error is a known problem with the "arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf"-toolchain, see [4.9 toolchain issue #50](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/issues/50).

The "`std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'"-error is related to gcc 4.8, see [std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, …)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327598/5107799). I'm not quite sure why this happens to you, since I was able to build opencv with the "gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64"-toolchain.

Maybe you have some luck with the way I did it: [How do I cross compile OpenCV for the Raspberry Pi with additional modules (highgui…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686422/how-do-i-cross-compile-opencv-for-the-raspberry-pi-with-additional-modules-high/40705325#40705325)

*Example CMakeLists.txt*

```
project(Test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Invoke cmake like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE -D PIROOT=$MOUNT_DIR -D TOOLROOT=$TOOLCHAIN ..
```